# PHP Average Date/Time in array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm building a monitoring system for in house. It needs to be able to workout the average of 4 dates and then add them to last element of the array (below) to work out the time the next file is expected.

So I have an array which looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-01-05 12:53
    [1] => 2016-01-05 13:05
    [2] => 2016-01-05 14:33
    [3] => 2016-01-07 16:07
)
```

and what I want to do is get the average of all these dates in the array.
I will then need to be able to add this average on to another date like below to workout an expected date.

```
2016-01-07 16:07 + Average
```

I want to be able to achieve this using PHP.
I hope I have explained it well enough?

I have tried this and was getting weird dates like 7586 for the year

```
$datesLoaded = array();
$intervals = array();
$expected = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $datesLoaded[] = $row['mydate'];
}

if (empty($datesLoaded)) {

    echo "empty array";

} else {

for ($i=0; $i < count($datesLoaded)-1; $i++) { 
    $firstFile = strtotime($datesLoaded[$i]);
    $nextFile = strtotime($datesLoaded[$i+1]);
    $interval = $nextFile-$firstFile;
    $intervals[] = $interval;
}

$numOfElements = count($intervals);

$sumOfIntervals = array_sum($intervals);

$meanTime = $sumOfIntervals / $numOfElements;

$lastDate = array_pop($datesLoaded);

$expectedTime = strtotime($lastDate) + $meanTime;

$expectedDate = new DateTime("@$expectedTime");

$expectedDateFormat = $expectedDate->format('j\t\h F - G : i');

$expected['expectedTime'] = $expectedDateFormat;

echo json_encode($expected);
```

Here are the variables echoed out

```
    (
    [0] => 720
    [1] => 5280
    [2] => 178440
)

    num of elements - 3
    sum of intervals - 184440
    mean time - 61480
    last date - 2016-01-07 16:07
    expected time - 1452244300
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: You mean the average time interval between all of the dates?

Comment: @cale_b see the edit.

Comment: @AbraCadaver No sorry the average date/time of the dates.

Comment: What does that mean?  What is the `average` given your array?

Comment: @AbraCadaver if you see the echo's you might understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$intervals` contains the array per your question, then what you need to use is [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) so that you can get the unix timestamp in order to average them.

So change this line:

```
$sumOfIntervals = array_sum($intervals);
```

To read:

```
$sumOfIntervals = array_sum(array_map('strtotime', $intervals));
```

Then, it will contain the average *timestamp*, and your meanTime and other calculations should do what you expect.

Comment: I am using 'last date - 2016-01-07 16:07' strtotime and adding the mean time to it

Comment: Unfortunately not, where I was expecting January it would show May.

Comment: Let's take a step back - what are you getting for the *average* timestamp?  (And, are you using the same dates that are in the array at the top of your question?)

Comment: So the array at the top of my question is the date we received our 'files' I then want to get an the average of those dates, to then add that average to the last date in the array at the top of the question. This will allow me to predict when we will get the next file.

Comment: Understood.  Can you please get me the value of the `$sumOfIntervals` when using the code I provided, with the array at the top of your question?

Comment: this is sum of intervals after using your code 
sum of intervals - 104455151672

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  That's the sum of like 70 timestamps.  It's way too big.  A timestamp for today would be something like 1451606400

Comment: So i want to do this - 2016-01-07 16:07 + Average and the way i work it out is the time stamp of the dates in the array and get the 'Mean' average (add them all up and divide by how many there are)

Comment: But you can't add or divide date-time strings in that format. It's a string, they don't have arithmetic. You _can_ add and divide timestamps (eg, the standard UTC seconds-since-the-epoch time is currently `1453221288`). So, can you show one of your date-time strings, and what _you_ believe to be the corresponding timestamp?

Comment: This - 1452182820 is a date time converted using strtotime and i want to add the mean date on to it to get a time in the future/ date

Comment: So - I've given you the tools.  You now need to test / debug and sort out why the values aren't right.  You aren't giving me enough information to work with, or answering my questions.

Comment: I think you have all misunderstood, my date-times are all converted to epoch times and then I add the average time (in epoch) to my date and is still returning odd dates.

Comment: None of this is clear from the question, so I suggest you write a new question which shows the actual values you're talking about. All your previous comments and the question itself suggested otherwise.